# Cannot Logging to ESI authenticated website Using requests in Python 3

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, authentication, python-requests

I'm trying to logging to my account in food.com for the last 2 days

```
url = "http://share.food.com/registration/login.esi"
```

Here is the code that I got from this site :

```
s = requests.Session()
other_url = 'http://www.food.com/recipe-finder/all/shrimp?pn=25'
p = dict(user = 'username', passwd = 'password')
r = s.get(url, params = p)
print(r.url)
```

here is the output of the url
I get the right url
but

```
r = requests.get(other_url, cookies = c, verify = False)
print(r.url)
```

returns `food.com/recipe-finder/all/shrimp?layout=desktop&pn=1`
Which implies that I did not logging.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: What does `r.history` show? If that is a non-empty list, your request was *redirected*, and the final URL was different.

Comment: That website has a bit of indirection. The form does not have a `target` in the HTML, so you will have to figure out which Javascript is setting the form's `target`.

Comment: I did but history was empty.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that url to login is
url = "http://share.food.com/registration/login.esi"

From this page, I found that the login form had hidden variables:
username
password (which is of type password)
pwdtext (which is a string type, but is not in the form)
login (shows as a button with the word "Log In"

Still using urlib.request or requests, I cannot logging.  How do i know? no cookie is created, and r.history is empty

Here is part of the HTML
    
    
    
    
     …

…

<**input id="aim_Email" class="email aimError" type="email" placeholder="" name="username"**>
     …  
     … 
    
    <**input id="aim_Password" class="password" type="password" placeholder="" maxlength="20"  name="password"**>
    <**input id="pwdtext" class="password" type="text" maxlength="20" name="pwdtext"   style="display: none;**"> … 
    <**input class="submit" type="submit" name="login" value="Log In"**>
     … 
    
    
    
     … 
     …